# How to make this gameobject instantiated as a child of a parent gameobject be positioned at an offset?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I've followed a C# in Unity tutorial to create a simple Space Invaders game. I'm now trying to understand the different functions being used.

There is this class called PlayerController. It also defines a shot gameobject, a field which is then supplied with a bullet prefab:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour
{
    private Transform player;
    public float speed;
    public float maxBound, minBound;

    public GameObject shot;
    public Transform shotSpawn;
    public float fireRate;

    private float nextFire;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        player = GetComponent<Transform> (); 
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        float h = Input.GetAxis ("Horizontal");
        if (player.position.x < minBound && h < 0)
            h = 0;
        else if (player.position.x > maxBound && h > 0)
            h = 0;
        player.position += Vector3.right * h * speed;
    }

    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetButton("Fire1") && Time.time > nextFire)
        {
            nextFire = Time.time + fireRate;
            Instantiate(shot, shotSpawn.position, shotSpawn.rotation);
        }
    }
}
```

The bullet gameobject used the class BulletController:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class BulletController : MonoBehaviour
{
    private Transform bullet;
    public float speed;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        bullet = GetComponent<Transform>();
    }
    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        bullet.position += Vector3.up * speed;
        if (bullet.position.y >= 10)
            Destroy(gameObject);
    }
    void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
    {
        if (other.tag == "Enemy")
        {
            Destroy(other.gameObject);
            Destroy(gameObject);
            PlayerScore.playerScore++;
        }
        else if (other.tag == "Base")
            Destroy(gameObject);

    }
}
```

From what I understand, a Transform object has values for position, rotation and scale.
So first, what does declaring x = GetComponent; do?

Second, where does "shotSpawn" takes its values from? From the object to which the code is applied to?

Third, the bullet gets instantiated exactly at the center of the square serving as the player ship's body, but I want it start higher at the y axis so it starts at the end of the cannon shape. It also seems to graphically intersect with the ship's body, so I wanted to move it slightly into the z axis. So how can you write that? I tried adding to the value of shotSpawn.position but it keeps declaring errors.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Create a child to player's ship. Move the child transform to where you want to spawn your bullet from, in your case at the end of canon. Then click on the gameobject where you have the playerController. And drag that child you created to the shotSpawn at the Inspector.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. A `GetComponent` means basically just grabbing a component of an object. Take a simple example: The `Main Camera` has a lot of components:

1.1. A `Transform` component. This component is used, as you understood, to define the position, rotation and scaling of an object

1.2. A `Camera` component. This has plenty of fields

1.3. A `Flare Layer` component.

etc.

These components can be grabbed via script. The reason developers use this is for their properties. For example, by saying `Transform playerTransformComp = player.GetComponent<Transform>();`, you will be able to write `playerTransformComp.position`. `position` is a property of objects of type `Transform`.

I don't think that the `GetComponent` you saw in the tutorial are useful because every game object has a transform component anyway, so if they declared the player as `public GameObject player;`, then used `player.transform.position` instead, it would have been way easier. In fact, I don't think it even makes sense to declare something as `Transform`, and then grabbing the `Transform` component. As @BugFinder said in your previous post, the tutorial is pretty bad overall.

---

`shotSpawn` takes its values from... itself! It is a public object, so I'm assuming you dragged & dropped the `shotSpawn` object from the scene into the script's fields. This means that the `shotSpawn` object from the script is the object you dragged & dropped on the script's fields. You can use all of its features and the dragged & dropped object will be affected. Thus, you can use `shotSpawn.position` and `shotSpawn.rotation`. I might be repeating myself here for a little bit, but please notice that `shotSpawn` is a `Transform` object, therefore you can use a typical `Transform` object's properties.

---

[The documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform-position.html) on `Transform.position` (as well as the one on `Transform.rotation` say you have to use `Vector3` objects to add or substract values to them.

One would do `shotSpawn.position + new Vector3(10f, 5f, 10f)`.
Naturally, you can also do

```
value = new Vector3(10f, 5f, 10f);
```

and then `Instantiate(shot, shotSpawn.position + value, shotSpawn.rotation);`

Also, please (for the future), try to ask one question per post, otherwise people will ignore your question or even flag it and it will be deleted. I was once like you, so I wouldn't do that, but please take this into consideration when making further posts.

Comment: So you're saying the same result could have been achieved using less steps with the player declared as GameObject instead? And the shotSpawn uses a "Bullet" prefab. Perhaps I overlooked and I can readjust the prefab's relative position. And thanks about the vector3 explanation! As I don't remember much from Java lessons at school, I assume declaring it as x = new Vector3 (X, Y, Z) is because it's an object rather than a data type?

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm saying. So the way I'd personally go about this is I'd declare it as ```public GameObject player;```, then drag&drop the player into the script field, then use ```player.transform.position``` instead of ```player.position```. Another advantage for this is you will extend your script easier. _ It doesn't matter what prefab it uses, the spawn point can be modified regardless. _ Yes, it's an Unity-specific object and not a data type.

Comment: The script is put onto the player object. You mean both doing that and then dropping the same player object into the GameObject field? And I suppose adjust the prefab position is simpler, but say you want to create a position offset that is not constant – that should be scripted using Vector3 values?

Comment: Yes and yes, at least that's how I do it to make sure I don't miss anything

Comment: Hmm.... I tried adjusting the prefab's position but it doesn't change where it is spawned. Maybe I didn't understand what you referred to? EDIT: But Aykut Karaca's method of create an empty child object, positioning it where I want the bullets to spawn and then putting that empty object into the Shot Spawn field does work fine.

Comment: What the other commenter said is what I was trying to say, but rephrased. Esentially, you handle ```shotSpawn```'s position in the ```Instantiate``` method, so naturally having a new ```shotSpawn``` object is perfect.

Comment: Yeah, but I thought you meant if you add position values to the prefab's transform settings it offsets the generation of the prefab spawn from the parent object.

Comment: That should also be true. However, I would have to look at your entire project to figure out why that doesn't work for you